# Htaccess - Detecting the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For my family members I was giving each person their own subdomain
(sister1.mydomain.com, sister2.mydomain.com, etc...)

I was using PHP to detect the domain, and then I'd load information related to the subdomain dynamically.

I'd like to get rid of the subdomains and use the power of `.htaccess` 
My goal is to give the same URL:

> www.mydomain.com/sister1
>
> www.mydomain.com/sister2
>
> www.mydomain.com/mommy
>
> www.mydomain.com/daddyo

Obviously, I don't plan to have literal working directories for each person.
I'd pass the "sister1" portion to a process.php script that takes care of the rest.

I've figure out how to do it by manually typing each `RewriteRule` in my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?sister1$ process.php?entity=sister1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?sister2$ process.php?entity=sister2[L]
RewriteRule ^/?mommy$ process.php?entity=mommy[L]
RewriteRule ^/?daddyo$ process.php?entity=daddyo[L]
```

I feel this is the long way of doing it.
Is there a more universal way of extracting the text after the first "/" forwardslash, and passing it to process.php?entity=$1 ?

I tried it this way:

> RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ process.php?entity=$1 [NC,L]

I'm getting the apache 404 error: "Not Found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a mandatory `/` in the beginning of your rule, i.e., you are always looking for something like `/sibling` in the URL. Your first examples have that first forward slash as optional due to the question mark after it.

You do not need a beginning forward slash - normally the rewrite rule picks up stuff after the domain name

```
www.example.com/string/mod/rewrite/gets/is.here
```

So just remove the starting slash and it should work.